# How to enable git multimail hook in gitolite

Tags: git, githooks, gitolite

I've cloned the git-multimail repo on my server, symlinked `post-receive` and `git_multimail.py` to `~/.gitolite/hooks/`

Then ran `gitolite setup --hooks-only`

In my `gitolite-admin/conf/gitolite.conf` I've added:

```
repo gitolite-admin
   config multimailhook.environment = gitolite
   config multimailhook.mailingList = 'list@example.com'
   config multimailhook.refchangelist = user@example.com,user@example.com
   RW+     =   user
```

And enabled in `~/.gitolite.rc`:

```
GIT_CONFIG_KEYS                 =>  'multimail.*',
```

Sendmail is properly delivering my other emails.

I'm expecting mails on commits, but nothing happens.
How to debug this?

I can see that there's an option to enable logging to `sys.stdout` in `post-receive`, but where can I see the logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just added more documentation about how to set up git-multimail with gitolite: https://github.com/git-multimail/git-multimail/blob/master/doc/gitolite.rst

With git 2.7 (Q4 2015), this setup process will be described in [git/git/contrib/hooks/multimail/doc/gitolite.rst](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4b1fd356b8f8ca464203174a47ab5fa6a5cbc26b/contrib/hooks/multimail/doc/gitolite.rst) in Git's source code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the actual directory where to put the hooks (I used wrong one: `.gitolite/hooks/`)

This directory is controlled in `.gitolite.rc` file, `LOCAL_CODE` variable (which is commented by default) as described here: http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#localcode

```
    # this one is managed directly on the server
    LOCAL_CODE                =>  "$ENV{HOME}/local",

    # or you can use this, which lets you put everything in a subdirectory
    # called "local" in your gitolite-admin repo.  For a SECURITY WARNING
    # on this, see http://gitolite.com/gitolite/cust.html#pushcode
    # LOCAL_CODE                =>  "$rc{GL_ADMIN_BASE}/local",
```

This means, after commenting out the default variable setting, you should put your hooks in `/home/git/local/hooks/common/` or enable repo specific hooks, as described in `.gitolite.rc`, set up executable permissions and run `gitolite setup --hooks-only`.

Comment: Good feedback, +1. That would have been my next suggestion.